# Approach to perform background task in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, cross-platform

I want to sync my local database with the server in my phonegap application.

I have two options

1) write a native service plugin in android and iOS  and perform a database sync with server

2) accessing database in phonegap itself and sending data to server using Ajax calls.

First approach is lethal.

In second approach (which I am using ) if I am initiating  a syncing process and pressing home button still my app will execute the JavaScript ( which is responsible for reading database from phone and syncing with the database ) until I remove the app from my recent list.

So wht I want to know is for 2nd approach is there anyother disadvantages exist apart from removing it from recent.

Is there any arguments where I need to switch to tht native service plugin and not to use the second approach

Comment: Close voters have a curtsey  to explain the reason please.as by asking this I am not shooting things in air.there are relevant reasons.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your app in IOs halts Plugin and user interaction (alerts) will halt when enters to the background mode (pause event).

You can detect when app is paused or resumed in order to continue your sync. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#pause

By other hand, first option is not absolutely secure, AppleStore seems to refuse background services that are not intended to geolocate device.

Comment: When I leave my app by pressing home , pause even is getting fired but my JavaScript code is still executing . For example I have created setInterval timer which is doing sync process after every 20 sec and it's being executing even after leaving an app.